# How to locate element? Illegal selector error (Capybara)

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I'm trying to use a page.find to locate a element using a text variable (both elements don't complete entirely), but when I tried to use the locator, I got the error: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified .

I don't know if the method is wrong or the the problem is the html element.

it 'test1' do 
        visit 'https://www.americanas.com.br/'

```
    $name = box for all the boys i've loved
    $author = Jenny Han

    fill_in 'h_search-input',   with: $isbn
    click_button 'h_search-btn'

    americanas = page.find($name).text      # <- here is the error
    americanas.click

    expect(find('table tbody tr')).to have_content $author
end
```

HTML elements:

`<h1 class="TitleUI-sc-1m3ayw0-16 cvOkHP TitleH1-c6mv26-0 VyqrE" icon="[object Object]">Box Book - For All The Boys I've Loved</h1>`

and

`<tr class="table-content__Tr-sc-6kkk7q-3 jFIPzA"><td class="table-content__Td-sc-6kkk7q-5 bPPRTT"><span class="text__TextUI-sc-1hrwx40-0 cKQvNJ">Author</span></td><td class="table-content__Td-sc-6kkk7q-5 bPPRTT"><span class="text__TextUI-sc-1hrwx40-0 cKQvNJ">Jenny Han</span></td></tr>`

What I got:

```
 1) test test1
 Failure/Error: americanas = page.find($name).text

 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError:
   invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
     (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.169)
     (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
 # ./spec/teste_spec.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` takes a selector type (defaults to :css), a locator, and then options - and returns a single matching element. In your code

```
americanas = page.find($name).text
americanas.click
```

You are not passing a selector type to `find` so it's assumed to be :css, but then you're passing a random string of text (I assume it's a string but it has no quotes around it in your code though?) which isn't a valid CSS selector - hence the error. After that you're calling `text` on the result of `find` which (if your find was correct) would get the text from the element (as a string) and then you call `click` on the string which doesn't make any sense since `click` is only supported on elements.  I think what you're trying to do is

```
page.find('h1', text: $name).click
```

but even that is going to fail because you have `$name = "box for all the boys i've loved"` but the contents of the h1 are "Box Book - For All The Boys I've Loved" which doesn't match in contents or case. You could use a case insensitive regexp by doing something like

```
page.find('h1', text: /for all the boys i've loved/i).click
```

but it all depends on what you're actually trying to do.

Then, assuming your table has more than one table row your expectation would probably need to be something like

```
expect(page).to have_selector('tr', text: $author)
```

Note: Based on the questions you've been asking it really seems like you could benefit from reading the Capybara docs and a few ruby tutorials.